# Error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

While trying to integrate latest Dagger 2 version, I am facing problem of Dagger auto generation. Dagger is not auto generating DaggerAppComponent in spite of several Rebuilds and Make Module App process.

**Application class:**

```
public class BaseApplication extends Application
{
    private AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        initAppComponent();
    }

    private void initAppComponent()
    {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent()
    {
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent
{
    void inject(BaseApplication application);
}
```

**AppModule:**

```
@Module
public class AppModule
{
    private BaseApplication application;

    public AppModule(BaseApplication app)
    {
        application = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext()
    {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication()
    {
        return application;
    }
}
```

**Dependency used:**

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste the logs which you are getting while building?

Comment: Where is the question? Why won't you post error logs? Give some seams to readers of your question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seems like I was using the wrong dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.x'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.x' // if you use the support libraries
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.x'
```

The above dependencies should be used if you are using classes in dagger.android.

The correct dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.x'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.x'
```

Comment: I've seen this for a quite few times already - what does it mean that "classes in dagger.android" are used?

Comment: Exactly, I have the same question like @az4dan.

Comment: In the case where you are using kapt for Java, changing it to annotationProcessor does the trick. I thought I read somewhere that kapt worked as well for Java but it seems to be buggy in some instances!

Answer (score 6):

You need these two lines

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
```

Use kapt instead of annotationProcessor when using kotlin.
Generated class like Dagger+AppComponentClass,
eg:DaggerAppComponent

Answer (score 5):

Adding the below dependency fixed the  issue for me for Java project

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27'
```

and for Kotlin project (after adding `kotlin-kapt`):

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27"
```

Comment: Can you try:
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.26"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem...What solved my problem was actually adding The view model to the ViewmodelModulle then add the annotation @Inject to the constructor of my view model. It could be a different issue for you but in my situation, this really helped. My code compiled without any problem

@Inject   <----- This was Missing in the constructor.

```
public MessageViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    mApp = application;
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. It was not an exact issue but it helped me to look at the annotation and I found out that I was missing some annotation to mention and once I mention that the error gone. But I am wondering the issue was different and we are getting different errors how should one get to know about exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try, go to File and

> Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

1.Clean the project
2.Rebuild
3.File-->Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

needs to run your APP once to generate "DaggerAppComponent"

Comment: Do you mean "you need to run your APP once to generate "DaggerAppComponent"" ?

Answer (score -2):

Chenge code to this,

```
 private void initAppComponent()
{
/*    DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                    .build();*/
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
        appComponent .inject(this)
    }
```

Other things are

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent
{
    void inject(BaseApplication application);
}
```

Why you need to inject same class where a component is built you can easily get context and application on Application class. Dagger can help you to find a dependent class.