# Project with dagger not compile after updating to Android studio Flamingo 2022.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

Just updated to the new Android Studio version - `Flamingo` and my project does not compile anymore, with error:

> error: cannot find symbol import package_name.DaggerAppComponent
>
> Cause: class clojure.lang.Reflector cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacRoundEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @6e60612a

I just update Android without any code changes or gradle changes.

Clean, invalidate cache restart does not help.

Dagger version `2.45` - Gradle version `7.42`

Tried multiple new Android studio versions, and reverted back to Electric Eel, also I have checked on 2 machines and this issue only on one of them for the same project.

Weird issue.

Comment: Can you add more details as your gradle files or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerAppComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251222/error-cannot-find-symbol-variable-daggerappcomponent)

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure you are using jdk 17 in your build. Go to the settings and change the Gardel jdk to 17, then in your app/build.gardel file change the code to:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 17
    targetCompatibility =17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember what was before, but after downloading and setting jdk 15 in project setting solved that issue.